# Broken layout of colored tables with new version of colortbl package

Tags: color, colortbl

we're having trouble with the new version of the colortbl package which breaks our layout of colored tables.  With the new version of the colortbl package (2012/02/13 v1.0a) the layout is utterly broken:

[image]

The old version (2001/02/13 v0.1j) gave a nice colored table as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Here's the MWE to reproduce the above tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\rowcolors{1}{orange}{white} 
\arrayrulecolor{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|lcr|}
\firsthline
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\columncolor{red}}c|}{Table Header} \\
Debian & Ubuntu & Arch Linux \\
Jessie & Trusty Tahr & Rolling Release \\
\lasthline
\end{tabular}%

\begin{enumerate}
\item Even if the \texttt{columncolor} of the first row is red the color is
ignored completely.
\item The value „Jessie“ is not visible (it's in the pdf but with same color
as the background).
\item There is an orange box in the first column at the end of the table.
\item If \texttt{hline} is used issue 2 and 3 don't occur.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Right now we have no idea why the behavior of the colortbl package (or maybe xcolor package?) changed so drastically.

Any help/suggestions with this issue is appreciated.

Comment: The tests I've done seems to indicate a conflict between the command `\rowcolors` (of the package `xcolor`) and the package `colortbl` when you use `\firsthline` and/or `\lasthline`.

Comment: yes I can confirm it's colortbl not xcolor if I revert that it works, I'm only sporadically online at present will look later....

Comment: glad to hear that you're looking into it.  
@skpblack: what kind of tests did you perform? how do you trace those conflicts at all? (I'm quite familiar with (La)TeX, but a novice when it comes to the internals of TeX, so I'd like to learn more...)

Comment: Effectively is an error with the new version of `colortbl`. I have tried with the `colortbl` version (2001/02/13 v0.1j) and works perfectly. Put the old `colortbl.sty` in the same directory together with *your file* and run.

Comment: yes, that's almost what we're doing right now. our workaround is to put the old `colortbl.sty` in a `Static` subfolder and export `TEXINPUTS=./Static/:$TEXINPUTS` before compiling. works, but inconvenient...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you have revisited again this problem? Sorry for my annoyance.

Comment: @skpblack just got back from vacation:-) this is on my stack of things to catch up on....

Answer (score 1):

I don't find a possible bug (possibly of `colortbl`), but meanwhile you should take a look in the package [`tabu`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf). This improves the main features of the packages for tables and arrays and seems fix your problem.

#### Changes

- Load the `tabu` package with `\usepackage{tabu}`
- You don't need to load separately the `colortbl` package if you use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.
- Replace `\begin{tabular}` ... `\end{tabular}` with `\begin{tabu}` ... `\end{tabu}`. Other specifications can be maintained.
- Use `\taburowcolors[2]{orange..white}` instead of `\rowcolors{1}{orange}{white}`, where `[2]` is the first row to be colored.

For now do not need other changes.

#### Here my complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\taburowcolors[2]{orange..white} 
\arrayrulecolor{red}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|lcr|}
\firsthline
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\columncolor{red}}c|}{Table Header} \\
Debian & Ubuntu & Arch Linux \\
Jessie & Trusty Tahr & Rolling Release \\
\lasthline
\end{tabu}%
\end{document}
```

And the

#### Result

> [image]

Comment: that would certainly be a solution, but we need backward compatibility with the colortbl package for older releases of our magazine. otherwise, we can't reproduce them (if we ever have to) unless we add some logic to treat those older issues

Comment: Surely @DavidCarlisle will review the `colortbl` package and if there is an error, he will update his package, hopefully.

Comment: Meanwhile you can use the [old colortbl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B23g3DBFautBU19ra1AzVTVlVzA/edit?usp=sharing) (2001/02/13 v0.1j) putting the file in your work directory